# Take an array and return a palindrome of odd length

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for a Pythonic way to take an array and return a palindrome whose left side is the input array. It is important that the length of the palindrome will be odd, i.e., the last element in the original array will not be replicated.

The shortest way I've found is:

```
arr + arr[-2::-1]
```

But it is somewhat "encryptic" IMO.

Is the a more readable convention or this?

Usage example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print a+a[-2::-1]
```

Comment: post the input sample

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Done.

Comment: Umm... Seems fine to me as long as you can interpet the slice notation... If you're really worried about it put it in a function with a suitable name...

Comment: Isn't this the most pythonic way to do it? What's wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 3):

The code you already have is good. It works properly and is most certainly pythonic. If you're worried about readability, then I suggest just putting it in its own function:

```
def palindrome(arr):
    return arr + arr[-2::-1]
```

If you want to simplify the complicated slice notation, this is essentially equivalent:

```
result = arr + arr[::-1][1:]
```

Or, if you really want to get rid of it entirely:

```
rev = list(reversed(arr))
rev.pop(0)
result = arr + rev
```

I however, would go with your original code.

Comment: That's the one: *I however, would go with your original code.*

Answer (score 2):

This is actually very Pythonic.
I would leave it this way and maybe add a comment for Python beginners.

A bit more readable is

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a.extend(a[-2::-1])
print(a)
```

Comment: Assuming that `a` is definitely a `list`... otherwise `a + a[-2::-1]` will work for strings, lists and tuples so I'd stick with that (I would argue it's not actually more readable than using `+`)... Also - this mutates the original list, which may not be desired...